# Centering text inside the BackgroundColor of a TextView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with a custom layout, the layout has 2 TextViews, the first one has a background and some padding. However the text in the first TextView can be of varied length (maximum of 4).

The current layout looks like this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="#"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:text="Example 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

And this results in the ListView looking like the following:

[image: Image 1]

I then added:

```
android:width="70dp"
```

To the first TextView which results in ListView looking like this:

[image: Image 2]

This is more how I want it to look with all the background's being aligned in the List, however, I want to have all of the text centered so they look like the #### in Example 4 but I am stuck on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:gravity="center"` for your first TextView.